# Change price of product depending on selected option

Tags: jquery, magento

A friend of mine is having a website where he sells different products and many of those products have different variants. For example one of these products can have a different color or different size. Depending on what you choose, the price should be changing. The code for the regular price looks like this:

```
<div id="WA_buybox">
<div id="WA_prices">
    <div id="WA_headline2">
        <p>Our Price</p>
    </div>
    <div id="WA_price">
        <p class="WA_price2">200&nbsp;€</p><-- Regular price without choosing an option -->
        <p class="WA_zzgl2">19% VAT</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
```

This is the part where you can choose an option:

```
<dd class="last">
<div class="input-box">
    <select name="super_attribute[149]" id="attribute149" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
        <option value="">Choose option…</option>
        <option value="28" price="139" data-label="1000 mm">1000 mm +139&nbsp;€</option>
        <option value="30" price="149" data-label="1200 mm">1200 mm +149&nbsp;€</option>
        <option value="32" price="159" data-label="1400 mm">1400 mm +159&nbsp;€</option>
        <option value="33" price="169" data-label="1500 mm">1500 mm +169&nbsp;€</option>
        <option value="34" price="179" data-label="1600 mm">1600 mm +179&nbsp;€</option>
        <option value="36" price="189" data-label="1800 mm">1800 mm +189&nbsp;€</option>
        <option value="38" price="199" data-label="2000 mm">2000 mm +199&nbsp;€</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

So far I can not change the value or the price of the option-tag. Also its not always mm but for example can be a different color. The only thing thats consistent is `+139&nbsp;€` with only the number changing.

What I want to achieve is that the price is changing depending on the the option you choose but here come the tricky part. This is what it looks like when you have choosen an option:

```
<dd class="last">
    <div class="input-box">
        <select name="super_attribute[149]" id="attribute149" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
            <option value="">Option wählen…</option>
            <option value="28" price="139" data-label="1000 mm">1000 mm -10&nbsp;€</option>
            <option value="30" price="149" data-label="1200 mm" class="selected">1200 mm</option>
            <option value="32" price="159" data-label="1400 mm">1400 mm +10&nbsp;€</option>
            <option value="33" price="169" data-label="1500 mm">1500 mm +20&nbsp;€</option>
            <option value="34" price="179" data-label="1600 mm">1600 mm +30&nbsp;€</option>
            <option value="36" price="189" data-label="1800 mm">1800 mm +40&nbsp;€</option>
            <option value="38" price="199" data-label="2000 mm">2000 mm +50&nbsp;€</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</dd>
```

The price has disappeeared and it also shows a "-" instead of a "+" when you have chosen a more expensive variant and want to switch to a less expensive one. I only have the possibility so far to change it using jQuery. I tried different things but none of them seemed to work. Do you guys have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `price="149"` attribute - that's what it's there for, so you don't need to dubiously parse the display text. Always use `base price + option price`, don't try to "keep" the previous calculation then +/-10 etc.  If you select a different option (eg 1500mm), it's not `200+149+20`,it's `200+169` (ie when changing the option simply forget the previous option)

Comment: oh okay I get it. But now I have the problem to filter the number in the price attribute and add it to the price standing in  <p class="WA_price2">200&nbsp;€</p>